# delphi firemonkey add custom font

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

i have to add a custom font for my labels on my firemonkey android app

so added new font in deployment section

and changed the `FMX.FontGlyphs.Android.pas` to this:

```
FontFile := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + CurrentSettings.Family + '.ttf';
if FileExists(FontFile) then
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.createFromFile(StringToJString(FontFile))
else
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.Create(FamilyName, TypefaceFlag);
```

then
i added the font to my label

```
Label1.StyledSettings :=  Label1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Family]
Label1.TextSettings.Font.Family := 'IRANSansMobile';
```

the font file deployed and exists on target mobile but label fonts not changed at all!

whats wrong with my code?!

**uodate**

for check if the font exists i added a button on form to run this and it saies me `exists`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  FontFile : string;
begin
FontFile := TPath.Combine( TPath.GetDocumentsPath , 'IRANSansMobile.ttf');
 if FileExists(FontFile) then
   showmessage('exists')
 else
   showmessage('not exists'); 
end;
```

**project tree:**
[image]

Comment: I assume that "exists on target mobile" means that you've debugged and the line containing createFromFile is being executed?

Comment: no , i updated font exixts code, how can i check if `createFromFile` executed?

Comment: By using a debugger

Comment: You don't need to modify FMX source files to use custom fonts. See [Custom Fonts on Android with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/custom-fonts-on-android-with-delphi-10-2-tokyo) and [True Type Font Iconography for Android and iOS Apps](https://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/true-type-font-iconography-for-android-and-ios-apps).

Comment: @RemyLebeau i do the same as your examples.my question is why this dont have effecte on my label !?

Comment: @peimanF. Well, you haven't commented yet on whether `FileExists()` reports true or false for the `.ttf` file. Sounds like it may be returning false

Comment: @RemyLebeau the font exixts and this is the reason i added the question in SO.if the font was not exists i must fix it...

Comment: @peimanF. You *think* it exists, but did you *verify* it? Did you *verify* `FontFile` contains the correct path you are expecting? Did you *verify* on the device's storage that the file is actually present at that path? What exactly does `FileExists()` return when you run it? Just because you configured the `.ttf` file in the Deployment Manager doesn't guarantee it was actually deployed properly, or in the folder you are expecting.

Comment: @peimanF. per [this blog](https://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/true-type-font-iconography-for-android-and-ios-apps): "*The string value set for any **TextSettings.Font.Family** property is **case sensitive** and has to match the internal, system registered, font name **which may be different than the file name of the font**.*" - did you *verify* that?